# route to an html page from controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an iframe and the source is a controller action method. This action method needs to return an HTML page (which has css, js files as external resources).

I am doing this because the url of the HTML file should never be known to outside world.

Is this possible? Is there anything we can do in routing level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would returning a [ContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) be what you are looking for? Then all you need to do is put the contents of the HTML file as the `Content`, set the `ContentType` and `ContentEncoding` as appropriate and return that.

Comment: Not sure whether ContentResult will server my purpose as the html has css and js files externally located. I am looking for a solution based on routing. Is there any way to create route for a controller method, which will route to an html file?

Comment: You said "I am doing this because the url of the HTML file should never be known to outside world." The CSS and js files are disconnected from the HTML file. They are different HTTP requests. If you need also to server the CSS and JS files in a similarly clandestine manner then you can use a controller action with a ContentResult on them too.